# Could not import DAGs in example_kubernetes_executor_config.py: No module named 'kubernetes' on MAC OS

Tags: python, macos, kubernetes, airflow

I am trying to install and configure Airflow on MAC via pip and venv. using this tutorial: https://my330space.wordpress.com/2019/12/20/how-to-install-apache-airflow-on-mac/. I am at the point were I am initializing the DB with command `airflow initdb`. When I do so, I get this output and error:

```
[2021-06-19 14:49:20,513] {db.py:695} INFO - Creating tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
WARNI [airflow.models.crypto] empty cryptography key - values will not be stored encrypted.
WARNI [unusual_prefix_f7b038312823bb0adacb1517baf49503823c7a6f_example_kubernetes_executor_config] Could not import DAGs in example_kubernetes_executor_config.py: No module named 'kubernetes'
WARNI [unusual_prefix_f7b038312823bb0adacb1517baf49503823c7a6f_example_kubernetes_executor_config] Install kubernetes dependencies with: pip install apache-airflow['cncf.kubernetes']
Initialization done
```

It states that I don't have kubernetes installed and it suggests that I run `pip install apache-airflow['cncf.kubernetes']`. When I do that, I get this error `zsh: no matches found: apache-airflow[cncf.kubernetes]`. I also tried these but none work:

```
pip install kubernetes
pip install apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes
```

I hope someone can help as I am stuck for a while :(

Comment: `[]` are special shell characters, so you need to quote them: `pip install "apache-airflow[cncf.kubernetes]"`

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I had a permission error and then used sudo python -m pip install apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes which solved this issue.